# Oracle creating N rows per value

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I modify the CTE below to INSERT rows into a new table T.

Based on the output below for table T I should have 4 rows for employee_id =1, 1 row for employee_id=3 and
2 rows for employee_id=7

```
CREATE TABLE T
  (seq_num integer  GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1) NOT NULL,
   employee_id NUMBER(6));


 CREATE TABLE  employees (
employee_id NUMBER(6)
 );

INSERT INTO employees 
(employee_id)
VALUES (1);

INSERT INTO employees 
(employee_id)
VALUES (3);

INSERT INTO employees 
(employee_id)
VALUES (7);

with rws as (
 select level rn
 from   dual
 connect by level <= 5
), emps as (
   select /*+ 
 materialize */e.*, 
round    ( 

dbms_random.value(1,5) ) n
  from   employees e
  )
  select employee_id, count (*) rw_count
 from   rws
 join   emps e
 on     rn <= n
group  by employee_id
Order by employee_id;

EMPLOYEE_ID    RW_COUNT
 1    4
 3    1
 7    2
```

Comment: `I should have 4 rows for employee_id =1, 1 row for employee_id=3 and 2 rows for employee_id=7` why? There should be random number of records for each employee.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use `group by`. It's almost untouched your query, I only added `insert` and removed aggregation:

```
insert into t (employee_id)
  with rws  as ( select level rn from   dual connect by level <= 5 ), 
       emps as ( select e.*, round (dbms_random.value(1,5) ) n from employees e )
  select employee_id
    from   rws 
    join   emps e  on rn <= n
    order by employee_id;
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0195c2ea78b15f15e213dfae9ec68c1e)